# Dynamically add components in specific fieldset in FormPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

Dynamically add text box in a specific **fieldset** here field set is Extra , as i have many fieldset in the form so here i am sharing the code of only one fieldsest.

for example,

```
 var extraData = [{

bodyStyle: 'padding-left:5px;',     
items:{
   xtype:'fieldset',
   title: 'Extra',

   collapsible: true,
   autoHeight:true,
   layout:'column',
    items:[{
    columnWidth:.5,
    layout: 'form',
    items: [{
        xtype:'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Comment',
        name: 'comment',
        anchor:'95%'
    }]
    },{
    columnWidth:.5,
    layout: 'form',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        name: 'last',
        anchor:'95%'
    }]
    }]
}

}];


 var fsf = new Ext.FormPanel({
            labelWidth: 75, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
            url:'save-form.php',
            frame:true,
            title: 'Enter New Groom Record',
             msgTarget: 'side',

            width: 650,
    items:extraData
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give id to the fieldset and the form.

Then do,

```
Ext.getCmp('myfieldset-id').add(my_dynamic_new_component);
Ext.getCmp('myform-id').doLayout();
```